# I can't get my drawing on the canvas as its own function

Tags: html, canvas

So in my class we're learning how to make animations in HTML5. we were given a sample of just 4 shapes and So I made a cloud. However, as you see, there is a `function drawCircle();`, and if I put the code to draw my cloud under that, it will appear in the canvas, but if i make a `function drawCloud();`, it won't show up at all. I even call the function at the end of the code and still nothing. Anyone know why or how to fix this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Demonstrates canvas drawing using drawing methods -->
<html>
<body style="text-align:center">
  <h1>HTML5 Canvas Drawing</h1>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:2px solid #BBBBBB;">
  </canvas>

    <script>
        var canv=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var c=canv.getContext("2d");

        var w = canv.width;
        var h = canv.height;

        function drawRectangle(){
            c.fillStyle="rgb(100,200, 240)";
            c.fillRect(100,100,200,200);

            c.strokeStyle="black";
            c.lineWidth=4;
            c.strokeRect(100,100,200,200);
        }

//        function drawCircle(){
//            c.fillStyle="red";
//            c.strokeStyle="black";
//            c.lineWidth=2;
//            c.beginPath();
//            c.arc(550, 200, 100, 0, Math.PI*2);  //x, y, radius, start angle, end angle
//            c.closePath();
//            c.fill();
//            c.stroke();
//        }

        function drawCircle(){
            c.beginPath();
            c.moveTo(170, 80);
            c.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
              c.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
              c.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
              c.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
              c.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
              c.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);

            // complete custom shape
              c.closePath();
              c.lineWidth = 5;
              c.strokeStyle = 'red';
              c.stroke();
        }

        function drawTriangle(){
            c.beginPath();
            c.lineWidth=3;
            c.strokeStyle="Blue";
            c.moveTo(200,350);
            c.lineTo(100,450);
            c.lineTo(300,450);
            c.lineTo(200,350);
            c.fillStyle="yellow";
            c.closePath();
            c.fill();
            c.stroke();
        }      

    drawRectangle();
    drawCircle();
    drawArc();
    drawTriangle();
    drawCloud();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, there isn't any function called `drawCloud`. You named the function `drawCircle` that is suppose to draw a cloud. Rename that function to `drawCloud` and comment out the actual `drawCircle` function. Also, there is no need to use `closePath()` method.

*Here's the fixed version of your code*

```js
var canv = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = canv.getContext("2d");
var w = canv.width;
var h = canv.height;

function drawRectangle() {
    c.fillStyle = "rgb(100,200, 240)";
    c.fillRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.lineWidth = 4;
    c.strokeRect(100, 100, 200, 200);
}

function drawCircle() {
    c.fillStyle = "red";
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.lineWidth = 2;
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(550, 200, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2); //x, y, radius, start angle, end angle
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
}

function drawCloud() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(170, 80);
    c.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
    c.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
    c.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
    c.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
    c.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
    c.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
    // complete custom shape
    c.lineWidth = 5;
    c.strokeStyle = 'red';
    c.stroke();
}

function drawTriangle() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.lineWidth = 3;
    c.strokeStyle = "Blue";
    c.moveTo(200, 350);
    c.lineTo(100, 450);
    c.lineTo(300, 450);
    c.lineTo(200, 350);
    c.fillStyle = "yellow";
    c.fill();
    c.stroke();
}

drawRectangle();
drawCircle();
drawCloud();
drawTriangle();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:2px solid #BBBBBB;"></canvas>
```